# Double swirling ring

Tags: modifiers, objects

I am creating a ring that has a base structure with a swirl around the main diamond.

More generally - I am having trouble creating a ring structure, with the top portion of the ring swirling around a center focal point.

I can create rings which have various bends, but I am uncertain of how to single out the top portion such that the simple deform modifier is only applied to that region.

---

Here are some examples of what I am attempting to create:

This is the type of thickness of the swirls I am trying to create, and is a fairly good example of the desired space between them, etc:

[image]

This example shows better the details of the rotation placement:

[image]

All I have been able to get so far is strange contortions of the entire ring - such as this:

[image]

Does anyone know of a simple way to do this?

Comment: I don't see how this can't be done with polygon modeling. Could you add an image of the *strange contortions*?

Comment: I think that using bezier curves as starting point will give you a lot of control over the swirls.

Comment: I am so sorry no one has been able to help. I would love to but I don't have any exp. in python for blender.